# apt failes on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I have set up icinga2 on an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS a long time ago. It worked without problems as well as apt-get update and the installations with apt.

Now suddenly apt no longer works, although no changes have taken place except those for monitoring.
I have looked at everything and can't find a solution.

There is no proxy set up and Ubuntu is set up as a virtual machine on a Hyper-V and ping to the IP address and FQDN works.

Apt-get failure:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post text as images. I have good eyesight and can barely read it. What about people who need special font settings or use a screen reader? What about search engines that index text?

Comment: In addition, the text is truncated in this screenshot.

Comment: "Network is unreachable" is just no connection. Do you have your DNS set to 8.8.8.8 or any other?

Comment: @gronostaj thanks for the info. I will keep that in mind next time.

Comment: @Myszsoda The DNS is entered and the IP address is obtained from the DNS on the AD server. But I also tried it with 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8, but nothing changed

Comment: Top right - Live Patch Settings:  Make sure the settings are correct and that you are logged on.  Make changes, restart and try Live Patch for updating.

Comment: This looks more like a problem in the network. Part of the addresses is IPv4, these timed out silently, part is IPv6, these return with an error message. Did you test the network from the VM to these addresses?

Comment: I have set up a new virtual machine to set up my second Icinga2 master. Also on the Hyper-V where the problem OS is running. On the new VM everything worked without problems.